# Div with a Header

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `<div>` which has a Label/Header displayed in Capitals letters. The `<div>` is `250px` wide.

Inside the `<div>`, I will place another `<div>` which will contain controls. This inner `<div>` should be `center` aligned and the outer `<div>` should automatically increase its height to accommodate the controls height.

The outer `<div>` and inner `<div>` should have a border.

Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I have setup a demo of my answer for you to check out. If it is not what you expected please provide more information. http://pastebin.me/42c81f55638f9adf9a4d614cac207db7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure what you are asking but maybe this will help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            div#wrapper { display:block; width:250px; height:auto; margin:auto; padding:0; border:1px solid #F00; }
            div#wrapper h1 { text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; }
            div#controls { display:block; width:100%; height:100px; margin:0; padding:0; border:1px solid #000; text-align:center; }
            div#controls a { display:inline; margin:0 5px; line-height:100px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">  
            <h1>header</h1>
            <div id="controls">
                <a href="#">control</a>
                <a href="#">control</a>
                <a href="#">control</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .panel { width: 250px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666; }
    .panel h1 { margin: 0 0 5px; padding: 0; text-transform: uppercase; }
    .panel .content { padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666; }
</style>
<div class="panel">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
        ... controls ...
    </div>
</div>
```